# Problems installing the python library for salvus

Tags: python, pip, conda

I'm having some problems installing the Python library for salvus (see [installation instructions](https://mondaic.com/docs/0.11.48/installation/python_packages#installing-the-dependencies)). When I use Conda to configure the **salvus** environment, the final step encounters a problem as the picture shows.
When I run the command

```
jupyter nbextension enable skip-traceback/main
```

the error hint is

> ```
> validating : problem found:\
> require? X skip-traceback/main
> ```

[image]

And I ignore that, follow the next step, the other problem is showed.
When I run the command

```bash
pip install ~/Salvus/python_packages/salvus-*.whl
```

trying to install the package, the file is not found. I don't understand where the file is nor where I need to download from.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Download the pip add-on on Visual Studio Code

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32376374)